# How to build appxpackage including both x86 and ARM builds using Azure Devops Pipelines?

Tags: azure-devops

When I build out of visual studio, I can right click on the project, select `Store/Create app packages..` and then in the dialog that opens I can select `I want to create packages for sideloading`. After that I am able to select which architectures to include in the appxbundle and VS will build out an appx containing all selected.

How do I setup my Azure Devops build pipeline to do this?

Currently, I am using "Visual Studio Build" step to build one for x86, and another for ARM, resulting in two separate `.appx` files.

Comment: Did you tried below arguments, how did it go?

Comment: I added those settings to the MSBuild arguments (I'm still using the GUI in pipelines, instead of the config files), but it kinda runs forever. I stop seeing logs from the build step and then the task times out. Still investigating

Comment: I corrected a little mistake of my answer. I tested with GUI visual studio build task. I was able to create a buddle with below MSBuild Arguments. Could you share the error log of your task, if it did work?

Answer (score 1):

You can try adding below arguments to the **MSBuild Arguments**

```
 /p:AppxBundlePlatforms="x86|ARM" /p:AppxBundle=Always /p:UapAppxPackageBuildMode=StoreUpload /p:AppxPackageDir="$(build.artifactStagingDirectory)\AppxPackages"
```

If you ran pipeline on a selfhosted agent. You can also use makeappx.exe to buddle appx files.
To use makeappx.exe, you need to add a powershell task after your build task to run below scripts. For details check [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/msix/package/create-app-package-with-makeappx-tool).

```
Set-Location -Path "C:\path to makeappx.exe"
.\makeappx.exe bundle /v /d "C:\My Files directory" /p MyBundle.appxbundle
```